# how to upload files to https server with certificates using curl or any other commands

Tags: ubuntu, https, curl

I am Trying to upload to my HTTPS server using curl .I am using curl for that ,the code is

```
curl -v --cacert /tmp/WIN-CLS.vdi.com.pem -T /etc/hosts \
--user administrator:pass_123 https://xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx
```

But i am getting error

```
*   Trying 192.168.1.230...
* Connected to 192.168.1.230 (192.168.1.230) port 443 (#0)
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /tmp/WIN-CLS.vdi.com.pem
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs/
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

I don't need to use -k option. I Googled about this, I downloaded a certificate and provided path in php.ini file. But still I am stuck in this error.

Any help would be appreciated